# How can I set image view height on tableview in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[image: enter image]

Tableview with imagepicker, When select any cell in tableview show image picker view, when I select the image from picker that image show into the exact cell in tableview, all are working fine, but the image show different layout, height I have exact height show image

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let path = IndexPath(row: self.selectedCell.row, section: 0)
            let cell = Tableview.cellForRow(at: path) as! CustomTableviewCell
            cell.documentImage?.image  = pickedImage
            cell.documentImage?.frame = CGRect()
        }
        Tableview.reloadData()
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableviewCell
        if SegmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
        {
            cell.prooofLable?.text = idProof[indexPath.row]
        }else  if SegmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
        {
            cell.prooofLable?.text = addressProof[indexPath.row]
            
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: change height of table view cell according to the size of imageview

Comment: Change the `contentMode` of `imageView` to `scaleAspectFit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 4**

Change image Contentmode of ImageView to `aspectfit` or `aspectfill` in storyoard and Tick on Clips to bound.

you can also do this programatically

```
cell.documentImage?.clipsToBounds = true
cell.documentImage?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Here is the full code in your method.

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let path = IndexPath(row: self.selectedCell.row, section: 0)
            let cell = Tableview.cellForRow(at: path) as! CustomTableviewCell
            cell.documentImage?.image  = pickedImage
            cell.documentImage?.clipsToBounds = true //clips out the image out of the cell
            cell.documentImage?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //fits the streacth view in image
            cell.documentImage?.frame = CGRect()
        }
        Tableview.reloadData()
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.documentImage?.clipsToBounds = true
```